# I want to retrieve values inserted on particular date using _id of mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to retrieve values inserted on particular date. Is this possible using mongodb "_id" field? as this contains embedded date time. I want to retieve values in mongodb shell not by using any application.

Comment: I want to display the timestamp value along with remaining fields in the collection. Could you please help on that? I want output as _id, field1, field2, <timestamp calculated from _id field>.

Answer (score 2):

While it is true that the ObjectId is based on a "timestamp" in part, generally this is a "client" library operation to "extract" this date from the ObjectId value.

You can do this with the JavaScript evaluation of [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/), but it will need to "scan" the entire collection, so is not very efficient:

```js
 db.collection.find(function() {
     return (
        ( this._id.getTimestamp().valueOf() - 
          this._id.getTimestamp().valueOf() % ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ) )
        == new Date("2014-07-14").valueOf() );
 })
```

That will basically compare to see if the `ObjectId` was created on the same day as the date provided. Other date math or methods apply to other intervals.

Comment: Thank you very much Neil, I also want to display the timestamp value along with remaining fields in the collection. Could you please help on that? I want output as _id, field1, field2, timestamp calculated from _id field.